# WinForms Docking Fill property is being ignored on window downsize, but not upsize

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following basic WinForm:

[image: Screenshot of Form]

[image: gif animation of behavior]

After scaling the form to a larger size than this designer view, all the controls adapt to the new height/width requirements of the parent containers just fine. 
All docking properties for the form controls are set to **Fill** each parent container. However, when the form is resized to smaller than the 'Designer' view, controls do not get resized correctly. See below:

[image: After downsizing]

I have checked for **MinimumSize** properties on all controls and this does not appear to be the problem. Designer code:

```
 private void InitializeComponent()
 {
  this.grpTasks = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
  this.tbTillButtons = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
  this.grpTransaction = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
  this.tableTransaction = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
  this.ctrlAddMemo = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
  this.ctrlFindbtn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
  this.ctrlPrint = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
  this.ctrlVoidLine = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
  this.ctrlFinish = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
  this.ctrlVoidall = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
  this.grpOtherTasks = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
  this.tableCashDrawer = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
  this.ctrlAddCash = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
  this.ctrlRemoveCash = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
  this.ctrlOpenDraw = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
  this.ctrlReconcile = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
  this.grpPayFor = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
  this.tablePayFor = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
  this.cmdBooking = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
  this.cmdInvoice = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
  this.grpTasks.SuspendLayout();
  this.tbTillButtons.SuspendLayout();
  this.grpTransaction.SuspendLayout();
  this.tableTransaction.SuspendLayout();
  this.grpOtherTasks.SuspendLayout();
  this.tableCashDrawer.SuspendLayout();
  this.grpPayFor.SuspendLayout();
  this.tablePayFor.SuspendLayout();
  this.SuspendLayout();
  // 
  // grpTasks
  // 
  this.grpTasks.Controls.Add(this.tbTillButtons);
  this.grpTasks.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.grpTasks.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
  this.grpTasks.Name = "grpTasks";
  this.grpTasks.TabIndex = 0;
  this.grpTasks.TabStop = false;
  this.grpTasks.Text = "Tasks";
  // 
  // tbTillButtons
  // 
  this.tbTillButtons.AutoSize = true;
  this.tbTillButtons.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.tbTillButtons.ColumnCount = 3;
  this.tbTillButtons.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 15.22492F));
  this.tbTillButtons.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 30.92374F));
  this.tbTillButtons.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 53.85135F));
  this.tbTillButtons.Controls.Add(this.grpTransaction, 2, 0);
  this.tbTillButtons.Controls.Add(this.grpOtherTasks, 1, 0);
  this.tbTillButtons.Controls.Add(this.grpPayFor, 0, 0);
  this.tbTillButtons.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.tbTillButtons.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 16);
  this.tbTillButtons.Name = "tbTillButtons";
  this.tbTillButtons.RowCount = 1;
  this.tbTillButtons.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
  this.tbTillButtons.TabIndex = 0;
  // 
  // grpTransaction
  // 
  this.grpTransaction.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.grpTransaction.Controls.Add(this.tableTransaction);
  this.grpTransaction.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.grpTransaction.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(430, 3);
  this.grpTransaction.Name = "grpTransaction";
  this.grpTransaction.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(494, 386);
  this.grpTransaction.TabIndex = 2;
  this.grpTransaction.TabStop = false;
  this.grpTransaction.Text = "Transaction";
  // 
  // tableTransaction
  // 
  this.tableTransaction.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.tableTransaction.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
  this.tableTransaction.ColumnCount = 3;
  this.tableTransaction.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
  this.tableTransaction.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
  this.tableTransaction.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
  this.tableTransaction.Controls.Add(this.ctrlAddMemo, 0, 0);
  this.tableTransaction.Controls.Add(this.ctrlFindbtn, 1, 0);
  this.tableTransaction.Controls.Add(this.ctrlPrint, 0, 1);
  this.tableTransaction.Controls.Add(this.ctrlVoidLine, 1, 1);
  this.tableTransaction.Controls.Add(this.ctrlFinish, 2, 0);
  this.tableTransaction.Controls.Add(this.ctrlVoidall, 2, 1);
  this.tableTransaction.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.tableTransaction.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
  this.tableTransaction.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 16);
  this.tableTransaction.Name = "tableTransaction";
  this.tableTransaction.RowCount = 2;
  this.tableTransaction.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
  this.tableTransaction.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
  this.tableTransaction.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(488, 367);
  this.tableTransaction.TabIndex = 2;
  // 
  // ctrlAddMemo
  // 
  this.ctrlAddMemo.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.ctrlAddMemo.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.ctrlAddMemo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
  this.ctrlAddMemo.Name = "ctrlAddMemo";
  this.ctrlAddMemo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(156, 177);
  this.ctrlAddMemo.TabIndex = 0;
  this.ctrlAddMemo.Text = "button7";
  this.ctrlAddMemo.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  // 
  // ctrlFindbtn
  // 
  this.ctrlFindbtn.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.ctrlFindbtn.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.ctrlFindbtn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(165, 3);
  this.ctrlFindbtn.Name = "ctrlFindbtn";
  this.ctrlFindbtn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(156, 177);
  this.ctrlFindbtn.TabIndex = 1;
  this.ctrlFindbtn.Text = "button8";
  this.ctrlFindbtn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  // 
  // ctrlPrint
  // 
  this.ctrlPrint.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.ctrlPrint.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.ctrlPrint.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 186);
  this.ctrlPrint.Name = "ctrlPrint";
  this.ctrlPrint.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(156, 178);
  this.ctrlPrint.TabIndex = 2;
  this.ctrlPrint.Text = "button9";
  this.ctrlPrint.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  // 
  // ctrlVoidLine
  // 
  this.ctrlVoidLine.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.ctrlVoidLine.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.ctrlVoidLine.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(165, 186);
  this.ctrlVoidLine.Name = "ctrlVoidLine";
  this.ctrlVoidLine.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(156, 178);
  this.ctrlVoidLine.TabIndex = 3;
  this.ctrlVoidLine.Text = "button10";
  this.ctrlVoidLine.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  // 
  // ctrlFinish
  // 
  this.ctrlFinish.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.ctrlFinish.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.ctrlFinish.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(327, 3);
  this.ctrlFinish.Name = "ctrlFinish";
  this.ctrlFinish.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(158, 177);
  this.ctrlFinish.TabIndex = 4;
  this.ctrlFinish.Text = "button11";
  this.ctrlFinish.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  // 
  // ctrlVoidall
  // 
  this.ctrlVoidall.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.ctrlVoidall.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.ctrlVoidall.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(327, 186);
  this.ctrlVoidall.Name = "ctrlVoidall";
  this.ctrlVoidall.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(158, 178);
  this.ctrlVoidall.TabIndex = 5;
  this.ctrlVoidall.Text = "button12";
  this.ctrlVoidall.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  // 
  // grpOtherTasks
  // 
  this.grpOtherTasks.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.grpOtherTasks.Controls.Add(this.tableCashDrawer);
  this.grpOtherTasks.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.grpOtherTasks.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(144, 3);
  this.grpOtherTasks.Name = "grpOtherTasks";
  this.grpOtherTasks.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(280, 386);
  this.grpOtherTasks.TabIndex = 1;
  this.grpOtherTasks.TabStop = false;
  this.grpOtherTasks.Text = "Cash Drawer";
  // 
  // tableCashDrawer
  // 
  this.tableCashDrawer.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.tableCashDrawer.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
  this.tableCashDrawer.ColumnCount = 2;
  this.tableCashDrawer.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
  this.tableCashDrawer.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
  this.tableCashDrawer.Controls.Add(this.ctrlAddCash, 0, 1);
  this.tableCashDrawer.Controls.Add(this.ctrlRemoveCash, 0, 1);
  this.tableCashDrawer.Controls.Add(this.ctrlOpenDraw, 1, 0);
  this.tableCashDrawer.Controls.Add(this.ctrlReconcile, 0, 0);
  this.tableCashDrawer.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.tableCashDrawer.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
  this.tableCashDrawer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 16);
  this.tableCashDrawer.Name = "tableCashDrawer";
  this.tableCashDrawer.RowCount = 2;
  this.tableCashDrawer.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
  this.tableCashDrawer.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
  this.tableCashDrawer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(274, 367);
  this.tableCashDrawer.TabIndex = 1;
  // 
  // ctrlAddCash
  // 
  this.ctrlAddCash.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.ctrlAddCash.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.ctrlAddCash.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 186);
  this.ctrlAddCash.Name = "ctrlAddCash";
  this.ctrlAddCash.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(131, 178);
  this.ctrlAddCash.TabIndex = 4;
  this.ctrlAddCash.Text = "button6";
  this.ctrlAddCash.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  // 
  // ctrlRemoveCash
  // 
  this.ctrlRemoveCash.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.ctrlRemoveCash.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.ctrlRemoveCash.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 186);
  this.ctrlRemoveCash.Name = "ctrlRemoveCash";
  this.ctrlRemoveCash.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(131, 178);
  this.ctrlRemoveCash.TabIndex = 3;
  this.ctrlRemoveCash.Text = "button5";
  this.ctrlRemoveCash.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  // 
  // ctrlOpenDraw
  // 
  this.ctrlOpenDraw.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.ctrlOpenDraw.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.ctrlOpenDraw.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 3);
  this.ctrlOpenDraw.Name = "ctrlOpenDraw";
  this.ctrlOpenDraw.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(131, 177);
  this.ctrlOpenDraw.TabIndex = 2;
  this.ctrlOpenDraw.Text = "button3";
  this.ctrlOpenDraw.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  // 
  // ctrlReconcile
  // 
  this.ctrlReconcile.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.ctrlReconcile.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.ctrlReconcile.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
  this.ctrlReconcile.Name = "ctrlReconcile";
  this.ctrlReconcile.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(131, 177);
  this.ctrlReconcile.TabIndex = 1;
  this.ctrlReconcile.Text = "button4";
  this.ctrlReconcile.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  // 
  // grpPayFor
  // 
  this.grpPayFor.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.grpPayFor.Controls.Add(this.tablePayFor);
  this.grpPayFor.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.grpPayFor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
  this.grpPayFor.Name = "grpPayFor";
  this.grpPayFor.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(135, 386);
  this.grpPayFor.TabIndex = 0;
  this.grpPayFor.TabStop = false;
  this.grpPayFor.Text = "Pay for";
  // 
  // tablePayFor
  // 
  this.tablePayFor.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.tablePayFor.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
  this.tablePayFor.ColumnCount = 1;
  this.tablePayFor.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
  this.tablePayFor.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
  this.tablePayFor.Controls.Add(this.cmdBooking, 0, 1);
  this.tablePayFor.Controls.Add(this.cmdInvoice, 0, 0);
  this.tablePayFor.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.tablePayFor.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
  this.tablePayFor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 16);
  this.tablePayFor.Name = "tablePayFor";
  this.tablePayFor.RowCount = 2;
  this.tablePayFor.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
  this.tablePayFor.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
  this.tablePayFor.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(129, 367);
  this.tablePayFor.TabIndex = 0;
  // 
  // cmdBooking
  // 
  this.cmdBooking.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.cmdBooking.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.cmdBooking.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 186);
  this.cmdBooking.Name = "cmdBooking";
  this.cmdBooking.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(123, 178);
  this.cmdBooking.TabIndex = 2;
  this.cmdBooking.Text = "button2";
  this.cmdBooking.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  // 
  // cmdInvoice
  // 
  this.cmdInvoice.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
  this.cmdInvoice.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
  this.cmdInvoice.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
  this.cmdInvoice.Name = "cmdInvoice";
  this.cmdInvoice.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(123, 177);
  this.cmdInvoice.TabIndex = 1;
  this.cmdInvoice.Text = "button1";
  this.cmdInvoice.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  // 
  // Main Form
  // 
  this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;
  this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(933, 411);
  this.Controls.Add(this.grpTasks);
  this.Name = "Main Form";
  this.Text = "Form1";
  this.grpTasks.ResumeLayout(false);
  this.grpTasks.PerformLayout();
  this.tbTillButtons.ResumeLayout(false);
  this.grpTransaction.ResumeLayout(false);
  this.tableTransaction.ResumeLayout(false);
  this.grpOtherTasks.ResumeLayout(false);
  this.tableCashDrawer.ResumeLayout(false);
  this.grpPayFor.ResumeLayout(false);
  this.tablePayFor.ResumeLayout(false);
  this.ResumeLayout(false);
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the GroupBoxes and all the parent containers.

Comment: @LarsTech For what specifically? Dock = Fill?

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, the way a Winforms form works is controlled by code, not by pixels.  Posting pixels does not help us help you find the problem in the code.

Comment: I'm just seeing the animation now.  The up-down resize doesn't look like it scales correctly.  But we have no code to look at, so who knows.

Comment: @HansPassant Fair point. Added designer code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with the same problem, I solved this issue by setting each button control's `AutoSize` property to `True`.

It now resizes whilst both upscaling and downscaling without a problem.